# psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation: value too long for type character varying(256)

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have created table with this column data type..

```
    create_table_sql = "create table "+table_name+" (\
                event_date varchar(100),\
                event_timestamp BIGINT,\
                event_name  varchar(65535),\
                event_params varchar(65535),\
                event_previous_timestamp BIGINT,\
                event_value_in_usd real,\
                event_bundle_sequence_id BIGINT,\
                event_server_timestamp_offset BIGINT,\
                user_id varchar(65535),\
                user_pseudo_id varchar(65535),\
                user_properties varchar(65535),\
                user_first_touch_timestamp BIGINT,\
                user_ltv varchar(65535),\
                device varchar(65535),\
                geo varchar(65535),\
                app_info varchar(65535),\
                traffic_source varchar(65535),\
                stream_id varchar(65535),\
                platform varchar(65535)                  )"
```

When I am trying to insert these below json data on redshift database using psycopg2 its gives the error.

```
 data_array = ['{"event_date":"20180625","event_timestamp":"1529948530245005","event_name":"firebase_campaign","event_params":[{"key":"medium","value":{"string_value":"(not set)"}},{"key":"firebase_event_origin","value":{"string_value":"auto"}},{"key":"source","value":{"string_value":"(not set)"}}],"event_previous_timestamp":"1529948527702005","user_pseudo_id":"ffb01b060c860317c9baba657ffe402d","user_properties":[{"key":"first_open_time","value":{"int_value":"1529949600000","set_timestamp_micros":"1529948488186000"}}],"user_first_touch_timestamp":"1529948488186000","device":{"category":"mobile","mobile_brand_name":"Samsung","mobile_model_name":"SM-A500G","mobile_marketing_name":"Galaxy A5","mobile_os_hardware_model":"SM-A500G","operating_system":"ANDROID","operating_system_version":"6.0.1","advertising_id":"44f5dd05-1f78-461a-be16-f6c4b1665920","language":"en-gb","is_limited_ad_tracking":"No","time_zone_offset_seconds":"19800"},"geo":{"continent":"Asia","country":"India","region":"Gujarat","city":"Ahmedabad"},"app_info":{"id":"app.trell","version":"3.3.8","firebase_app_id":"1:808772988865:android:8db93cca16602100","install_source":"com.android.vending"},"traffic_source":{"name":"(direct)","medium":"(none)","source":"(direct)"},"stream_id":"1051639513","platform":"ANDROID"}', '{"event_date":"20180625","event_timestamp":"1529947540672001","event_name":"firebase_campaign","event_params":[{"key":"medium","value":{"string_value":"(not set)"}},{"key":"firebase_event_origin","value":{"string_value":"auto"}},{"key":"source","value":{"string_value":"(not set)"}}],"event_previous_timestamp":"1529947540484001","user_pseudo_id":"4696ce1fc56aae5c026b2d2408bde2cd","user_properties":[{"key":"first_open_time","value":{"int_value":"1529949600000","set_timestamp_micros":"1529947525415000"}}],"user_first_touch_timestamp":"1529947525415000","device":{"category":"mobile","mobile_brand_name":"Samsung","mobile_model_name":"SM-G935F","mobile_marketing_name":"Galaxy S7 Edge","mobile_os_hardware_model":"SM-G935F","operating_system":"ANDROID","operating_system_version":"8.0.0","advertising_id":"a952abd5-952f-45de-af1f-721805044eb0","language":"en-gb","is_limited_ad_tracking":"No","time_zone_offset_seconds":"19800"},"geo":{"continent":"Asia","country":"India","region":"Maharashtra","city":"Mumbai"},"app_info":{"id":"app.trell","version":"3.3.8","firebase_app_id":"1:808772988865:android:8db93cca16602100","install_source":"com.android.vending"},"traffic_source":{"name":"(direct)","medium":"(none)","source":"(direct)"},"stream_id":"1051639513","platform":"ANDROID"}']
```

Trying to insert using the code below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data_array)
df.to_sql(table_name, conn, index=False, if_exists='replace')
```

This is the stack trace of the error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/trell/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1226, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/home/ubuntu/trell/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 854, in do_executemany
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation: value too long for type character varying(256)


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bq_to_s3_migration.py", line 232, in <module>
    import_json_from_s3_to_rs(table_name, s3_bucket)
  File "bq_to_s3_migration.py", line 180, in import_json_from_s3_to_rs
    df.to_sql(table_name, conn, index=False, if_exists='replace')
  File "/home/ubuntu/trell/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2712, in to_sql
    method=method,
  File "/home/ubuntu/trell/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 518, in to_sql
    method=method,
  File "/home/ubuntu/trell/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1320, in to_sql
    table.insert(chunksize, method=method)
  File "/home/ubuntu/trell/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 756, in insert
    exec_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
  File "/home/ubuntu/trell/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 670, in _execute_insert
    conn.execute(self.table.insert(), data)
  File "/home/ubuntu/trell/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 982, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/ubuntu/trell/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 287, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/ubuntu/trell/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1101, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/home/ubuntu/trell/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1250, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/home/ubuntu/trell/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1476, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "/home/ubuntu/trell/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/home/ubuntu/trell/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 152, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/ubuntu/trell/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1226, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/home/ubuntu/trell/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 854, in do_executemany
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation) value too long for type character varying(256)

[SQL: INSERT INTO events_20180625 ("0") VALUES (%(0)s)]
[parameters: ({'0': '{"event_date":"20180625","event_timestamp":"1529948530245005","event_name":"firebase_campaign","event_params":[{"key":"medium","value":{"string_value ... (979 characters truncated) ... rce":"com.android.vending"},"traffic_source":{"name":"(direct)","medium":"(none)","source":"(direct)"},"stream_id":"1051639513","platform":"ANDROID"}'}, {'0': '{"event_date":"20180625","event_timestamp":"1529947540672001","event_name":"firebase_campaign","event_params":[{"key":"medium","value":{"string_value ... (985 characters truncated) ... rce":"com.android.vending"},"traffic_source":{"name":"(direct)","medium":"(none)","source":"(direct)"},"stream_id":"1051639513","platform":"ANDROID"}'}, {'0': '{"event_date":"20180625","event_timestamp":"1529948527702004","event_name":"firebase_campaign","event_params":[{"key":"medium","value":{"string_value ... (997 characters truncated) ... rce":"com.android.vending"},"traffic_source":{"name":"(direct)","medium":"(none)","source":"(direct)"},"stream_id":"1051639513","platform":"ANDROID"}'}, {'0': '{"event_date":"20180625","event_timestamp":"1529947540484000","event_name":"firebase_campaign","event_params":[{"key":"medium","value":{"string_value ... (1003 characters truncated) ... rce":"com.android.vending"},"traffic_source":{"name":"(direct)","medium":"(none)","source":"(direct)"},"stream_id":"1051639513","platform":"ANDROID"}'}, {'0': '{"event_date":"20180625","event_timestamp":"1529939515508006","event_name":"firebase_campaign","event_params":[{"key":"medium","value":{"string_value ... (1090 characters truncated) ... rce":"com.android.vending"},"traffic_source":{"name":"(direct)","medium":"(none)","source":"(direct)"},"stream_id":"1051639513","platform":"ANDROID"}'}, {'0': '{"event_date":"20180625","event_timestamp":"1529939930985001","event_name":"CREATE_POST_SUCCESS","event_params":[{"key":"item_name","value":{"string_ ... (1113 characters truncated) ... 7aa","install_source":"iTunes"},"traffic_source":{"name":"(direct)","medium":"(none)","source":"(direct)"},"stream_id":"1051639514","platform":"IOS"}'}, {'0': '{"event_date":"20180625","event_timestamp":"1529939930986002","event_name":"CREATE_POST_FINISH","event_params":[{"key":"item_name","value":{"string_v ... (1111 characters truncated) ... 7aa","install_source":"iTunes"},"traffic_source":{"name":"(direct)","medium":"(none)","source":"(direct)"},"stream_id":"1051639514","platform":"IOS"}'}, {'0': '{"event_date":"20180625","event_timestamp":"1529939930987003","event_name":"EMOTIONTAG_COUNT","event_params":[{"key":"item_name","value":{"string_val ... (1107 characters truncated) ... 7aa","install_source":"iTunes"},"traffic_source":{"name":"(direct)","medium":"(none)","source":"(direct)"},"stream_id":"1051639514","platform":"IOS"}'}  ... displaying 10 of 49081 total bound parameter sets ...  {'0': '{"event_date":"20180625","event_timestamp":"1529950522044233","event_name":"NARRATION_CLICK","event_params":[{"key":"firebase_screen_class","value":{ ... (1058 characters truncated) ... rce":"com.android.vending"},"traffic_source":{"name":"(direct)","medium":"(none)","source":"(direct)"},"stream_id":"1051639513","platform":"ANDROID"}'}, {'0': '{"event_date":"20180625","event_timestamp":"1529950553109238","event_name":"EMOTION_NEXT_CLICK","event_params":[{"key":"firebase_screen_class","value ... (350 characters truncated) ... 1238","user_pseudo_id":"edbabf0bc47bad8008d6b9037c439563","user_properties":[{"key":"first_open_time","value":{"int_value":"1529172000000","set_times'})]
```

I checked each column of the table no column have varchar lengh of 256. All varchar is 65535 as you can see in `create_table_sql`. Also tried `json.load()` and `json.dumps()` before inserting data using pandas data frame to redshift with no luck.

Any lead is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a complete setup to try the end product, but the sql insert does not seem right (insert ("0")).  Consider removing the single quotes from your data_array.

With the single quotes df resolves to this:

```
0
0  {"event_date":"20180625","event_timestamp":"15...
1  {"event_date":"20180625","event_timestamp":"15...
```

but without the quotes:

```
    event_date   event_timestamp  ...   stream_id platform
0   20180625  1529948530245005  ...  1051639513  ANDROID
1   20180625  1529947540672001  ...  1051639513  ANDROID
```

Which is probably what you want.

Best regards.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the answer. How to remove the single quote? I tried printing 0th index of the json string. Thats why I tried json.loads and json.dumps to remove the single quote. It's not printing the single quote but the left curly bracket. I mean single quotes doesn't exists.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot help you there as I do not know the bigger picture.  All I see is the assignment shown in the question - and it includes single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, I got the same error even though none of the Pandas DataFrame columns were longer than the database column datatypes. Strangely, adding the `schema='schemaname'` argument to `df.to_sql()` fixed it for me. Instead of `df.to_sql(name='schemaname.tablename', ...)` try `df.to_sql(name='tablename', schema='schemaname', ...)`.